# window.onload on firefox 30

Tags: firefox-addon, onload, firefox-addon-sdk, addeventlistener

I need some help with firefox addon. I've got a function that gets some values from the page and uses them to fill new window text area.

```
var ticket = document.getElementsByName('ticket_id');
var addr = document.getElementsByName('address_id');
var text = "Your address is "+addr[0].value+", ticket number is "+ticket+",";
smsWin = window.open("http://mysite.net/", "New window", "height=250");

smsWin.onload = function () {
  smsWin.document.getElementById('textsms').innerHTML = text;
};
```

The function is called by an action button in Firefox

```
var button1 = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "style-tab1",
  label: "Do magic",
  icon: "./icon-64.png",
  onClick: function() {
    require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: self.data.url("close.js")
    });
  }
});
```

It works perfect on ScratchPad and in the addon on Firefox 29. But in latest Firefox 30 the smsWin.onload function part doesn't seems to be working (even if i put alert('1') inside), while the window still opens. Any ideas on how to fix it?

UPD. 
Also tried this

```
smsWin.addEventListener("load", function() {
  smsWin.document.getElementById('textsms').value = text;
}, false);
```

And it doesnt work in a plugin as well (but works on ScratchPad and FF29). Changing `load` to `DOMContentLoaded` cnahges nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've done some workaround. Seems like window.onload part doesnt work in FF30 cause of secutity updates. But if the window is an iframe it works perfectly. So I just modified needed pages with `var smsWin = document.createElement('iframe');` and so on, and suddenly `smsWin.onload = function () {...}` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The reason it works from scratchpad is because you are running the code `window.open("http://mysite.net/", "New window", "height=250");` in the mode of "Environment" > "Content"</s>

If you set "Environment" to "Browser" in scratchpad then you will see it won't work.

You can't do window.open from addon code. If you want to open a window you have to use `Services.ww`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowWatcher

See how to open window with features here:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=428535&p=2321231&hilit=openWindow#p2321231

```
  var ww = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"]
                 .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowWatcher)

  ww.openWindow(null, "chrome://browser/content/browser.xul", "_blank",
       "chrome,all,dialog=no", "http://www.gemme.pl/");
```

---

Ok i see you are doing add-sdk and that the window opening is not the problem but the window loading. Try using `DOMContentLoaded`.

Although sdk confuses the heck out of me. Because when a window opens the load that triggers on window is when xul finishes loading. Then you have the page that loads. But try the `DOMContentLoaded` in place of the `load` and let me know how it works.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, gonna try it. The most suspicious part that addon works in FireFox 29, but i found nothing relevant in changelogs of 30 version

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same - works in FF29 and ScratchPad, but not on FF30. I still cant find anything in changelogs.